# Ruby if block logic returning unexpected results

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm working on a Ruby exercise taking a number and returning the word equivalent.  Below is code for a function with an if statement I'm working on.  I've puts different strings to help me trace where my errors are.

The first three conditionals seem to function as I've intended them to. However, the conditional that returns 'puts The teens translator works' is somehow true despite it not meeting the conditions of the numbers I pass in.

I've included some of the numbers I've been passing to illustrate what I mean.  My intention is for the condition to be true if the number is greater than 13 but less than 20, not evenly divisible by 10, and not 11, 12, 13 or 15.  If I pass in 41 for example, it appears the condition is true because "The teens translator works" prints.  I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
def in_english
    if @number == 11 || @number == 12 || @number == 13 || @number == 15
        puts "The number is 11, 12, 13 or 15"
    elsif (@number >0 && @number < 10)
        puts "Hello I made it hear"
    elsif (@number >= 10 && @number < 100 && @number%10 == 0)
        puts "The number is greater than equal 10 & < 100 and divisible by 10"
    elsif ((@number > 13 && @number < 20 ) && @number%10 != 0 && @number != 11 ||    @number != 12 || @number != 13 || @number != 15)
        puts "The teens translator works"
    elsif (@number > 20)
        puts "Over twenty_trans"
    else
        puts "End of if block"
    end
end

Say.new(47).in_english
Say.new(41).in_english
Say.new(52).in_english
```

Comment: How is `@number` defined? What is the relevance of `Say.new` to the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if @number == 11 || @number == 12 || @number == 13 || @number == 15
```

...you can write this:

```
if [11, 12, 13, 15].include? @number
```

And, instead of this mess:

```
elsif ((@number > 13 && @number < 20 ) && @number%10 != 0 && @number != 11 ||    @number != 12 || @number != 13 || @number != 15)
```

...you can write this:

```
elsif [14, 16, 17, 18, 19].include? @number
```

...or this:

```
elsif @number == 14 or (16..19).include? @number
```

> My intention is for the condition to be true if the number is greater
>   than 13 but less than 20, not evenly divisible by 10,

What numbers between 13 and 20 are evenly divisible by 10?

Comment: `What numbers between 13 and 20 are evenly divisible by 10?` - 19 - for sufficiently large values of 19...

Comment: This was very helpful.  Sorry for the delay checking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the number is more than 13 and less then 20, it can't be 11, 12 and 13 anyway (it's already more than 13). So, you don't have to check.

Second problem are Parentheses.

This:

```
((@number > 13 && @number < 20 ) && @number%10 != 0 && @number != 11 ||    @number != 12 || @number != 13 || @number != 15)
```

will be avaluated following way:

```
(@number > 13 && @number < 20 ) && @number%10 != 0 && @number != 11
```

OR

```
@number != 12
```

OR

```
@number != 13
```

OR

```
@number != 15
```

It checks 41 for a first condition and it will be false. However, as soon as it checks it for second condition 47 != 12 is true. So, it will show teens translator.